# Downloading files with Makefile rules

Tags: linux, download, makefile, wget

I was planning something like:

```
URLS=www.host.com/file1.tar.gz www.host2.com/file2.tar.gz
$(somefunc $URLS): #somefunc produces downloads/file1.tar.gz downloads/file2.tar.gz
   mkdir -P downloads
   wget whatever # I can't get the real url here because the targets don't contain the full url anymore

myproject: $(somefunc URLS)
   #Files should already be in downloads/ here
```

The problem I have is that if I convert URLS with somefunc I lose the urls, if I don't I can't use it as a target to avoid being downloaded when it is already there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If `somefunc` only modifies the path, not the actual filename, and there are no duplicates, you could try searching `$(URLS)` for the original filename.

Maybe something like this? (untested)

```
$(somefunc $URLS): #somefunc produces downloads/file1.tar.gz downloads/file2.tar.gz
   mkdir -p $(dir $@)
   wget $(filter $(addprefix %/,$(notdir $@)),$(URLS)) -O $@
```

- `$(notdir $@)` evaluates to `file1.tar.gz` for one of the targets.
- `$(addprefix %/,file1.tar.gz)` evaluates to `%/file1.tar.gz`
- `$(filter %/file1.tar.gz,www.host.com/file1.tar.gz www.host2.com/file2.tar.gz)` evaluates to `www.host.com/file1.tar.gz`.

(Presumably you want an `http://` on there too?)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I don't think you can do it directly with make.  But here's a solution if you are willing to use some scripting:

```
$(URLS):
    @for url in ${URLS}; do \                                               
        if [ ! -e $$(somefunc $${url}) ]; then \
            echo wget $${url}; \
            wget $${url}; \
        fi \
    done
```

Comment: But that will download all URLS each time one target is missing. I was thinking in a Makefile solution rather than relying in wget downloading several URLS at the same time.

Comment: @Yogur - okay, I've completely revamped my solution.